# How can I press this online flyer image to get more information in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to parse information from this flyer. The problem is that the information I need (item name, price, etc.) is not visible on the original HTML. To get the information I must first click the item image on the flyer and then it gives a popup with the information which then at that point can be parsed from the html. I highlighted the perusable image in the first picture html. How can I click this using Selenium to open up that popup? How can I click on the path? My goal is to iterate through all items on the flyer but to do this I need to know how to click that image :( Please help. Thank you.

**PICTURE 1:**
[image]

**PICTURE 2:**
[image]

Comment: can you post url ..?

Comment: Here is the link although to actually view the flyer you will have to select any city in Ontario (the city doesn't matter all flyers are the same for Ontario): http://ontario.foodland.ca/flyer/

Comment: There is nutritional information ...is that you want to display??

Comment: All I want to know is how to click on the image on the flyer to spawn that popup in the second picture. Nutritional information i'm not so much worried about... more so the item name, price, description.

Answer (score 0):

One Solution what I found is all of those tiny images are `path` elements that belongs to `SVGVectorElement`

Find those elements using tagName and perform click On it.

The below code will navigate through all the pages and click on all the images and prints the name of the product

Make sure the page is loaded fully before calling this

```
public static void flyerPageImageDetails(WebDriver driver) {
    //switching to the flyer frame
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe.framePage")));
    //To get the total no of pages
    String pageText = getCurrentPageText(driver);
    if (pageText != null && pageText.matches("\\d+.*of.*\\d+")) {
        int pageCount = Integer.valueOf(pageText.substring(pageText.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1));
        for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
            sleepForASecond();
            System.out.println("Printing Image Details for Page " + i);
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
            clickAllPointsInImage(driver);
            //Moving to next image
            driver.findElement(By.id("arrowNext")).click();
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
        }
    } else {
        clickAllPointsInImage(driver);
    }
}

private static String getCurrentPageText(WebDriver driver) {
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='slider']//span[@class='ttContent']"));
    if (elements.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return elements.get(0).getText();
}

private static void clickAllPointsInImage(WebDriver driver) {
    WebElement currentImageElement = getVisibleImageElementFromList(driver);
    //Finding all the path elements for the visible image
    List<WebElement> paths = currentImageElement.findElements(By.tagName("path"));
    for (WebElement path : paths) {
        try {
            path.click();
            //To get the title text 
            List<WebElement> title = driver.findElements(By.className("title-pd"));
            if (!title.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(title.get(0).getText());
            }
            driver.findElement(By.className("close")).click();
            sleepForASecond();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
}

private static WebElement getVisibleImageElementFromList(WebDriver driver) {
    List<WebElement> imageElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'span')]/div/div[1]/div[2]"));
    for (WebElement imageElement : imageElements) {
        if (imageElement.isDisplayed()) {
            return imageElement;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static void sleepForASecond() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DrangAndDrop.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

This code took 6 mins to click on all the images on all the pages.And I've used hardcoded wait bcoz it takes some time for the popup to be invisible so that it affects the click on another image